# nmap: nping echos to stderr

Tags: node.js, macos, nmap

On macOS High Sierra, **nping** is available via **brew install nmap** and it works:

> nping --tcp-connect --count=1 --dest-port=443 8.8.8.8

```
Starting Nping 0.7.70 ( https://nmap.org/nping ) at 2018-04-04 18:46 PDT
libnsock mksock_bind_addr(): Bind to 0.0.0.0:0 failed (IOD #1): Invalid argument (22)
SENT (0.0030s) Starting TCP Handshake > 8.8.8.8:443
RCVD (0.0166s) Handshake with 8.8.8.8:443 completed

Max rtt: 13.790ms | Min rtt: 13.790ms | Avg rtt: 13.790ms
TCP connection attempts: 1 | Successful connections: 1 | Failed: 0 (0.00%)
Nping done: 1 IP address pinged in 0.02 seconds

nping --version
Nping version 0.7.70
```

Note the line echoed to stderr by macOS:

> libnsock mksock_bind_addr(): Bind to 0.0.0.0:0 failed (IOD #1): Invalid
>   argument (22)

Any clever npingers able to explain how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the command with root privilege. Try this:

sudo nping --tcp-connect --count=1 --dest-port=443 8.8.8.8